# How to hide entire column that does not contain a cell with a fill

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table (X by Y) with random cells filled in red (it can range from all cells filled in in the column, to some filled in cells, to no filled in cell in the column). I would like to hide the columns that have no cells filled in. The code below looks for the cells filled in red and hides the entire column regardless if there are any cell not filled in. I would like to hide the columns with no cells filled in.

```
 Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Selection
  If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then 'finds the filled in cells
  Columns(cell.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hides the column with filled in cells
  End If
  Next
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say columns with no cells filled in. what do you mean? a data sample (screenshot would help)

Comment: **[1.]** Loop though the columns of the table **[2.]** Use `Application.Worksheetfunction.CountA` to check for blank cells. You can also use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank` for this purpose **[3.]** Hide the column

Answer (score 0):

This will hide columns with no red cells in the column:

```
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim c as long
  For c = 1 to selection.columns.count

      Dim redFound as Boolean
      redFound = False

      Dim r as Long
      For r = 1 to Selection.Rows.Count

          If Selection.Cells(r,c).Interior.Color = vbRed Then 
              redFound = True
              Exit For
          End If
      Next

      Selection.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = redFound

   Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need identify a variable to record the status which need be hidden or not. Here I named 'Flag' to record whether column need be hidden or not.

```
Sub Hidden_Column()
Dim Flag As Boolean
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iClm As Integer
Dim ColorNum

With Sheet1
    For iClm = 1 To .Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Flag = True
        For iRow = 1 To .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ColorNum = .Cells(iRow, iClm).Interior.ColorIndex
            If ColorNum <> -4142 Then       'no color
                Flag = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iRow
        If Flag = True Then
            Columns(Cells(iRow, iClm).Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next iClm
End With
End Sub
```